# Spring security 6.1 help needed

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have this Config in my spring boot 3 but yesterday I opened the Config to see some error because authorizeHttpRequests is deprecated and I looked through the documentation but I still can’t figure out

```
@Bean     
 public SecurityFilterChain adminFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {         http         .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider2());         http.securityMatcher("/admin/\*\*").authorizeHttpRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()                 .and()                 .formLogin()                 .loginPage("/admin/login").usernameParameter("username")                 .loginProcessingUrl("/admin/login")                 .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/AdminDashBoard")                 .permitAll()                 .and().logout()                 .logoutUrl("/admin/logout")                 .invalidateHttpSession(true)                 .logoutSuccessUrl("/");            return http.build();     }
```

I tried using Google

Comment: There are certain guidelines to post a question, could you please go through that and edit yourquestion

Answer (score 1):

Spring boot version 3.0 uses version 6.0 security, but spring boot 3.1 already uses version 6.1
And if we talk about the upgrade from 6.0 to 6.1, it is easier than you imagine

If you go to the deprecated method, you will see documentation showing how to use the method. Take the **[authorizeHttpRequests()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ccrzd.png)** method as an example.
Here we configure everything related to **authorizeHttpRequests()**
using the following methods:

```
authorizeHttpRequests()
    .requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**").permitAll()
    .requestMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER")
    .requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
```

After configuring **authorizeHttpRequests()**, it returned **SecurityConfigurer** to us, but for further configuration we need to call the **and()** method that **HttpSecurity** returned to us.

Now the documentation tells us that in 6.1 **authorizeHttpRequests()** is deprecated, Use **[authorizeHttpRequests(Customizer)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXhjs.png)** instead.
In this case, **Customizer** is used, that is, the same **AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer** that returned the deprecated **authorizeHttpRequests()** method.
That is, the old code must be replaced with a new one:

```
.authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
        .requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**").permitAll()
        .requestMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER")
        .requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
)
```

The same should be done with other deprecated methods, such as:

- cors().disable() >>> csrf((csrf) -> csrf.disable())
- exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/errors/access-denied") >>> exceptionHandling((exceptionHandling) -> exceptionHandling.accessDeniedPage("/errors/access-denied"))
- logout().deleteCookies("remove") >>> logout((logout) -> logout.deleteCookies("remove"))

I hope I have explained these small changes in a clear way. Have a nice projects =)